# Looping through year,month,day,hourly files in bash and average them to make daily files

Tags: bash, loops, netcdf

I am new to bash scripting. I have all individual hourly netcdf files with no timestamp and I want to average them to daily files. I have used the following script:

```
set echo
for (( year = 2019 ; year <= 2019 ; year++))
do
   for ((month = 1 ; month <=12 ; month++)); do
   for day in $(seq 1 $iy); do
      if [$month -eq 1] || [$month -eq 3] ||  [$month -eq 5] || [$month -eq 7]  || [$month -eq 8] || [$month -eq 10] || [$month -eq 12]; then 
        iy = 31 
     elif [$month -eq 4] || [$month -eq 6] || [$month -eq 9] || [$month -eq 11]; then 
      iy = 30 
     else 
      iy = 28
     fi
    dd=$day
            
        if [ $day -lt 10 ]; then
          dd=0$day
        fi 
           mm=$month
           if [ $month -lt 10 ]; then
             mm=0$month
           fi

      ncea -o ./$year$mm$dd??.nc ./$year$mm$dd.nc  #average hourly to daily

But it does not read all the files and shows the following error for all months:  

./: line 8: [11: command not found
./: line 8: [11: command not found
./: line 8: [11: command not found
./: line 8: [11: command not found
./: line 8: [11: command not found
./: line 8: [11: command not found
./: line 8: [11: command not found
./: line 10: [11: command not found
./: line 10: [11: command not found
./: line 10: [11: command not found
./: line 10: [11: command not found
./: line 13: iy: command not found
```

Please advise why is the script not able to loop through all files to make daily files?
Thank you for your effort and time.

Comment: Insert a space after all `[` and before all `]`. Remove spaces around `=` in all assignments. You have other issues: you use variable `$iy` before assigning it, you have lines of code inside loops that do not need to be looped over. But your main issue is probably a good understanding of `bash` programming and general programming (your use of a variable before it was assigned probably indicates that you don't really understand all this). You should consider reading a good introductory book or taking a programming course.

Comment: paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: Thanks Renaud and Jetchisel for your responses. I wish I would have known shellcheck.net before!! It was very helpful for beginners like me.

Answer (score 0):

The below script worked perfectly. I used shellcheck.net to edit the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set echo
for (( year = 2014 ; year <= 2014 ; year++))
do
   for ((month = 1 ; month <=12 ; month++)); do
   iy="31"
   for day in $(seq 1 $iy); do
      dd=$day
      if [ "$month" -eq 1 ] || [ "$month" -eq 3 ] ||  [ "$month" -eq 5 ] || [ "$month" -eq 7 ]  || [ "$month" -eq 8 ] || [ "$month" -eq 10 ] || [ "$month" -eq 12 ]; then 
        iy="31"  
     elif [ "$month" -eq 4 ] || [ "$month" -eq 6 ] || [ "$month" -eq 9 ] || [ "$month" -eq 11 ]; then 
      iy="30" 
     else 
      iy="28"
     fi
            
        if [ "$day" -lt 10 ]; then
          dd=0$day
        fi 
           mm=$month
           if [ "$month" -lt 10 ]; then
             mm=0$month
           fi
```